# Implementing Comparable interface produces "UnsupportedOperationException : ListIterator does not support set" error

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do is to sort an arraylist of objects by a property (Integer) in Java.

I've found several posting about using Comparable/Comparator for this perpose, but none of them seem to be related to "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException" error. So, I'm writing a question here.

I followed [this page](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/), and have been trying to use Comparable interface.

Here is part of my coding

```
public class Word implements Comparable<Word>{

private String wordName;
private int number;

 // There are only simple constructers, getters and setters 

@Override
public int compareTo(Word word) {
    int compareNumber = ((Word) word).getNumber();
    return compareNumber - this.number;

    }
}
```

The main method is like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //There are some irrelevant methods and fields

    List newWordList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String wordName : WordList) {
        //WordList is of List<String>, containing several "wordName" (i.e. string values)

        //Get how many duplicate "wordName" inside the list
        int number = Collections.frequency(WordList, wordName);            
        Word word = new Word(wordName, number);
        newWordList.add(word);
    }

    List noDupList = SetUniqueList.setUniqueList(newWordList);
    Collections.sort(noDupList, new Comparator<Word>() {
        @Override public int compare(Word w1, Word w2) {
            return w2.getNumber() - w1.getNumber();
        }
    });

}
```

Then, this produces "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: ListIterator does not support set".

I'm confused particularly about "ListIterator", since I don't use this class nor do I use Set class either.

I would appreciate if you would give any insight.

Comment: Doesn't `SetUniqueList.setUniqueList()` use a set internally?

Comment: @Takendarkk my answer should have been yours, really; good spotting!

Comment: @fge I just glanced at the docs, you actually did the research and explained it. Hats off to you.

Answer (score 8):

@Takendarkk is on the correct track here...

From the [javadoc of `SetUniqueList`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/list/SetUniqueList.html):

> The List interface makes certain assumptions/requirements. This implementation breaks these in certain ways, but this is merely the result of rejecting duplicates. Each violation is explained in the method, but it should not affect you.

Well, in your case, it does (affect you)...

[`Collections.sort()` expects a `List` as an argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-); and a `List` is supposed to be able to produce a [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html). And `Collections.sort()` relies on that... Except that `SetUniqueList` returns a `List` whose `ListIterator` implementation does not support the [`.set()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#set-E-) operation.

Therefore you cannot use `SetUniqueList` for your use case. You have to write your own methods to produce a `List` without duplicates.

Three examples; first, the "naïve" one:

```
public static <T> List<T> onlyUniqueItemsFrom(final List<T> originalList)
{
    final Set<T> set = new HashSet<>(originalList);
    return new ArrayList<>(set);
}
```

Another "better" version:

```
public static <T> List<T> onlyUniqueItemsFrom(final List<T> originalList)
{
    final Set<T> set = new HashSet<>(originalList.size());
    final List<T> ret = new ArrayList<>(originalList.size());
    for (final T element: originalList)
        if (set.add(element))
            ret.add(element);

    return ret;
}
```

Or, with Java 8:

```
public static <T> List<T> onlyUniqueItemsFrom(final List<T> originalList)
{
    return originalList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

Meh, with Java 8 you can have both operations done in a single method:

```
    return originalList.stream().distinct().sorted(yourComparatorHere)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `SetUniqueList` is in Apache Commons Collections. It is a `List` implementation that doesn't allow duplicates.

Comment: Well, looks like it's broken somewhat, isn't it? That's just me but I have never really trusted Apache commons for anything serious...

Comment: I don't use it either, but in this case they're blameless. if a `List` doesn't allow duplicates, it's never going to be compatible with any sensible `sort` implementation (how is a swap supposed to happen without an intermediate stage with a duplicate?).

Comment: @pbabcdefp Blameless? They return a `List` which breaks the `List` contract? I wouldn't call that "blameless" ;)

Comment: Which part of the contract do they break? As far as I know all a `List` has to support is `get` and `size`. That's pretty much all the `List`s returned by `Collections.unmodifiableList` do.

Comment: @pbabcdefp No, they break the contract in the sense that a `List` can produce a `ListIterator` which a `Set` obviously cannot!

Comment: Fair enough, it does break the contract, but your answer is still wrong. It does return a `ListIterator`, it's just that the `ListIterator` doesn't support the `set` method.

Comment: Thank you very much. For confirmation, is it right to consider that SetUniqueList is technically incompatible with the List class, and that therefor developers need to find another way to make a no-duplicate list if they want to use List class? I'll try your "onlyUniqueItemsFrom". Again, thank you all so much!

Comment: It is incompatible at least in the sense that the answer explains. If you don't need to sort your list afterwards then I gather it is safe to use it... But then again I have moved away from Apache commons a long time ago. This is one case where `SetUniqueList` cannot be used, but for some other use cases it may be perfectly fine.

Comment: @fge, @YMD - Don't blame Apache.  The `ListIterator.set` method is optional.  The javadoc explicitly states that this exception may be thrown *"... if the set operation is not supported by this list iterator"*.